# Crystal reports, sub-reports, and shared variables

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a formula @InitVars in the page header which includes the following, and similar lines:

```
shared numbervar runWaste:=0;
```

In Details v, I have a sub-report, which has a formula @SetRunWaste:

```
shared numbervar runWaste;
if (OnFirstRecord) then
(
if not(isnull({x.x-or})) and 
not(isnull({x.y-override})) and {x.y-override} = true then
runWaste:={x.x-or} 
  else
runWaste:= {x.x}
);
runWaste
```

I can see the output of this formula in the sub-report is 18.00.

However, both in another sub-report, in Details az, and in the main report in Details w (as a test), I have the following formula @test:

```
shared numbervar runWaste;
runWaste;
```

In both places, it shows as 0.00.

Why is it showing 0 not 18?

I'm using Crystal Reports version 11.0.0.895.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that @InitVars is in the page header, not the report header. It is resetting the variable to 0 at the top of every page.

Moving @InitVars to the report header fixed it so the correct number comes up in the sub-report in Details az.

I still see some odd behavior when I include the variable in the main report, but since that was just for debugging, not the main target, I don't care.

Answer (score 1):

I have a vague memory that I'm now having a hard time substantiating about shared variables not passing back up from a subreport.  Still looking; good thing it's Friday afternoon.

**Edit**:  I can't find what I was looking for, so a general thought.  Check evaluation time, and make sure that the later section on the main report is evaluating after the subreport (WhilePrintingRecords might be your friend here).

Comment: Hmm, adding whileprinting records to @test caused it to work in the page footer, but it is still incorrect in details w. It also is incorrect on later pages...

Comment: And you're sure it's not getting reset somewhere, either somewhere else in the main report, or in one of the subreports?

Answer (score 0):

From the article [Adding Sub reports ,Find Sub Total and Grand Total(To main Report)](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/26316-Adding-Sub-reports-Find-Sub-Total-Grand.aspx):

> Crystal Reports is a business
>   intelligence application used to
>   design and generate reports from a
>   wide range of data sources. Sub
>   Reports are child reports of the main
>   report which can be embedded in main
>   report. Sub reports are very much
>   useful in building reports.
>
> Adding Sub reports find the sub total
>   and grand total of each sub report in
>   the main report
>
> Main report
>
> Sub Report 1
>
> Sub Total: sum (LabTotal )
>
> Sub Report 2
>
> Sub Total: sum (ItemTotal)
>
> Grand Total
>
> Sub reports are very useful option in
>   crystal report. Suppose we want to
>   find
>
> Adding Crystal report
>
> 1. Add New Item->Crystal Report
> 2. If we want to create Crystal Report our own format select “As a Blank
>      Report” from crystal report gallery
> 3. Right Click on the “Database fields” in the Database fields and
>      select tables from the database then
>      make Links (if necessary)
> 4. Right Click from “Details Section” and Add sub report.
> 5. Repeat the same things that we have done in the main report and drag
>      needed fields to details section sub
>      report
>
> For Eg: We are creating labour report
>   the total labour rate can be
>   calculated as
>
> In Formula field –name LabTotal
>
> WhilePrintingRecords; Shared NumberVar
>   LabTotal := Sum
>   ({PC_LABOUR_DETAILS.Total})
>
> ({PC_LABOUR_DETAILS) -- table Total
>   ---field
>
> and add sum of LabTotal in to the sub
>   total field
>
> If we have another sub report to add
>   ion the main page ,again right click
>   on the “Details Section” and add new
>   section ->Details(b) And repeat step 4
>   and 5 Here we are adding second sub
>   report for material and subtotal of
>   materials can be caculated as
>
> In Formula field –name ItemTotal
>
> WhilePrintingRecords; Shared NumberVar
>   ItemTotal := Sum 
>   {PC_MATERIAL_DETAILS.Total})
>
> ({PC_MATERIAL_DETAILS) --table Total
>   -- field
>
> and add sum of ItemTotal in to the sub
>   total field
>
> Main report
>
> To find the grand total of both sub
>   reports
>
> In Formula field name-GrandTotal
>
> WhilePrintingRecords; Shared NumberVar
>   ItemTotal; Shared NumberVar LabTotal;
>   NumberVar TotalAmount; TotalAmount :=
>   ItemTotal+LabTotal; TotalAmount

Comment: @kristina: Please don't just copy and paste content from other sites without giving proper credit to the original author. Thank you.