# Sum of RT Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, cumulative-sum

i'm trying to calculate a sum of a running total, I've googled this an i'm struggling to find a solution. I need to calculate 2 field values and then group the sum of that result with the jobs, i then want to create a sum of that in the footer of the report.

currently i have a shared number variable which gets zeroed out and its placed in the group header

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar EndingBalance;
EndingBalance := 0;
```

I then have the calculation that i need the results for and this is placed in the details section of the report

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar EndingBalance;
EndingBalance := EndingBalance + {timesheet1.Time_Hours}*{timesheet1.Time_BillRate}
```

and finally i have the total of that added to the group footer

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar EndingBalance;
EndingBalance
```

all of the above works as it should and does exactly what i need it to do....
However, i need to return the total of all the records shown in the report footer and I'm unable to create a sum of it, any ideas how to resolve this problem?
Thanks, Luke

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958448/crystal-reports-sub-reports-and-shared-variables

Comment: You good sir are a legend! Exactly what i was looking for!